# Increase quality of movie from images with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a movie from a set of images with FFMpeg; I tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i pol00%3d.png -b:v 100M test.avi
```

The resulting movie, however, is a bit blurry compared to the original images at times, and I get this message:

```
[mpeg4 @ 00000152fc04b1c0] bitrate tolerance 4000000 too small for bitrate 100000000, overriding
```

I also get the following output:

```
frame=  257 fps= 51 q=2.0 Lsize=   76441kB time=00:00:51.40 bitrate=12183.0kbits/s speed=10.3x
video:76430kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.015302%
```

If I naively roughly sum up the individual png image sizes, I get roughly 120 MB.
So, how can I increase the bitrate? I tried using mpeg and H.264, but the files created by these are not readable by WMP. File size does not matter, I just want a movie of the same quality as the individual images.

Comment: See first command at https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18549

Comment: I went down to crf 1, and now it looks fine, but it still could look a little bit better; the pictures contain a lot of very thin lines which look a little bit too broad in the movie. It looks similar to when you are loading a picture and the picture is still buffering. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the methods [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23053), but the output won't play in many players.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!